# Standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^m$ and induced topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}^m$ equipped with the standard topology $\tau_m$ and, for $n<m$, consider the set $E=\{\mathbb{R}^n\times \{(\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{m-n \ \text{copies}})\}\}$, then $E$ naturally induces a subset topology $\tau_E$ on itself, inherited from the topology of $\mathbb{R}^m$, I wonder do we have the following correspondence:

$\forall \ U\in \tau_E$, we have $f(U)\in\tau_n$; and $\forall \ V\in \tau_n$, we have $V\times \{(\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{m-n \ \text{copies}})\}\in\tau_E$,

where $f$ is the natural projection map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tau_n$ is the the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. More explicitly, is the map $i:E \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $i((a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,0,0,\ldots,0))=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ a homeomorphism with respect to the topology above? My pictorial reasoning seems to give me an affirmative answer, but I just want to make sure that I didn't miss extreme cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $i:E \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is indeed a homeomorphism. To see this, we first need to check that it is continuous, but this follows directly since for every open ball $B_r(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have
$$
i^{-1}(B_r(x))=B_r(x)\times \{0,...,0\}\subset E.
$$
This set is open in $E$ with the subspace topology since we can write it as the intersection of some open cylinder $B_r(x)\times \mathbb{R}^{m-n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and the set $E$.

It is easy to give an inverse for $i$ (just take the map $j:  \mathbb{R}^n \to E$ defined by $j(a_1,...,a_m)=(a_1,...,a_n,0,...,0)$). You can check the continuity of the inverse $j$.